# how do i show 2nd ajax data in 1st ajax page?

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax

in my code Product Name will change with Brand name and i will show the info of products..
but the info is not showing properly... if i run only getdetails.php page from url i can see the info of product bt i can't see it from user page and i need to show the data in user page....
my user page code:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if( $_SESSION['type']!='user')
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        return;
    }
    require_once("dbconnect.php");
    $sql = "SELECT Brand FROM info";
    $rslt = mysql_query($sql);
    $options = "";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rslt))
    {
        $options .= "<option>$row[Brand]<option>";
    }
    mysql_close();
   ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function loadDetails()
            {
                var xmlhttp;
                var pname = document.getElementById("list").value;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {   
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getdetails.php?name="+pname,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadDetails();">
    <center>
        <h1>Product</h1>
        <fieldset>
        <legend><label><b>Choose Your Product</b></label></legend></br>
            <label><b>Brand Name</b></label>
            <select id="list" onchange="loadDetails();"><?php echo $options; ?></select>
            <div id="details"></div>
        </fieldset>
```

my getdetails page :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( $_SESSION['type']!='user')
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        return;
    }
    require_once("dbconnect.php");
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $sql = "SELECT Name FROM info WHERE Brand='$name' AND quantity > 0";
    $rslt = mysql_query($sql);
    $options ="";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rslt))
    {
        $options.="<option>$row[Name]<option>";
    }
    mysql_close();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function Details()
            {
                var xmlhttp;
                var lname = document.getElementById("plist").value;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {   
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("dtil").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","details.php?pnam="+lname,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
<body onload="Details();">
            <label><b>Product Name</b></label>
            <select id="plist" onchange="Details();"><?php echo $options; ?></select>
            <?php echo "<table id='dtil' border=3></table>";


            ?>
    </body>
```

how do i get the data of table in "dtil"?? is there is any efficient way to do those  code in one page??

Comment: any suggestion is welcome.....

Comment: For your own sake, look into: `mysqli`/`PDO`, `jQuery` and `SQL injection` first! It will make your life (and application) much easier and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Your Option Rows that you are dynamically generating have no `value` field attached to them, hence `var pname = document.getElementById("list").value;` returns nothing. Also you have named it `plist` in your HTML code.

Other remarks that I urge you to search for both ease and safety:

- Look into `mysqli` and `PDO`. `mysql` is both unsafe and can become deprecated in the soon future.
- Look into `jQuery`, it is so much easier than pure `javascript`. Having an understanding of `CSS` selectors makes understanding `jQuery` even easier.
- For the sake of security, look into `SQL injection.`